# How can a path animation be used as an action in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, bezier-curves, constraints, conversion

I animated a rollercoaster using a *Bezier Curve* and a *Follow Path Constraint* affecting the vehicle. 
Then I tried to use the automatically created action in the game engine but the *Action Actuator* has no effect .

- How can this action be used in the BGE?
- Can the *Path Animation* alternatively be converted into keyframes?

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/04/01/model-download-rollercoaster/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert actions such as constraints to keyframes with *Object > Animation > Bake action*. (see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-constraint-to-a-keyframe))

[image]

You may want to enable *Clear parents* to replace parent/child with keyframes:

[image]

Also note that without *Clear Constraints* enabled, constraints will not be removed, possibly giving unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, which object(s) should be selected when baking the action? Baking the constraint leads to strange offsets which can't be relocated perhaps swaped axis. Baking the bezier-curve seems to move around the current position.

Comment: @stacker The object following the path should be baked. Make sure you remove the constraint(s) afterwards

Comment: Now the vehicle moves as expected, the view from the camera which is parented to the vehicle seems to be on the wrong track, but this would be another question. Thanks this helped much, everyday another mighty tool.

Comment: @stacker you might be able to fix that by enabling *clear parents* (I just tested and it seems to work) you can also automatically remove the constraints with *clear constraints*

Comment: Sorry that was one of my scripts for the (currently unpluged) head tracker it changed camera orientation to some weird settings. Now its fun, thanks again.