# BGE : Access a Nurbs path from python

Tags: python, animation, game-engine

I need to trigger an action (a 30 frames animation) attached to a nurbs path, made by keyframing the "evaluation time" in the curve menu. But it's not listed in the objects of my scene, I checked :

```
    logic.scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

    # print all the objects in the scene
    for obj in logic.scene.objects:
            print(obj.name)
```

It's confusing because it IS listed in the outliner along with the other objets..?

So how can I access my curve so I can use `playAction()`? Is there another way to acces an action in the scene?

Comment: OK, found the solution https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/how-can-a-path-animation-be-used-as-an-action-in-the-game-engine and marked my own Q as dupli.