# In bge, how would I zoom using mouse scroll in ortho view?

Tags: python, game-engine

[image]

How would I incorporate the ortho zoom to my mouse wheel?

This seems close to what I need, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
cam = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects['Camera']

if not "DefaultFOVset" in cont.owner:
    cam.ortho_scale = 20
    cont.owner["DefaultFOVset"] = True

FOV = cam.ortho_scale

if cont.sensors["MWHEELUP"].positive:
    if FOV < 20:
        FOV += 1 # linear increase
        FOV /= 0.9 # exponential increase
    if FOV > 20:
        FOV = 20
elif cont.sensors["MWHEELDOWN"].positive::
    if FOV > 10:
        FOV -= 1
        FOV *= 0.9
    if FOV < 10:
        FOV = 10

cam.ortho_scale = FOV
```

Here's another one, I can only get it to zoom out. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58556/37524

Answer (score 1):

- Typo on the line 18
  `positive::` to `positive:`
- You need 2 sensors for each of detect wheel up and down.
  And the sensors have to be connected to the python controller.
  This is why you got only one of zoom out or in.
- You have to make the names in blender to be consistent with the names in the script, also the script file name.[image: screen shot]

**Advice:**
You can open console from menu `Window > Toggle System Console`. The console shows error messages from BGE when BGE is running.
Be carful, closing the console window closes whole blender.