# Springy Animation to Unity

Tags: animation, modifiers, export

I'm trying to make an animation with using a curve modifier. But when I export it as .fbx file, my object doesn't follow the curve. It just moves linear. what should I do? thanks.

Comment: From a modifier, I don't think you can. But https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/how-can-a-path-animation-be-used-as-an-action-in-the-game-engine

Comment: You can't do it. You can export animations with aramture or shapekeys to fbx.