# Multiple objects with equal spacing on Follow Path constraint?

Tags: animation, path

I want to place multiple objects with equal space on a circle to animate it later using the Follow Path constraint. Is there a easy way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some more vital information. Are you talking about different objects or identical objects? Have they roughly the same size? Equal space from the objects centers or equal space between the objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a follow path constraint, use a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > *Follow Path* type of parent on your object.

Adjust framing as necessary, then go to the *3D View Menu > Object > Animation > Bake Action*. Tick to activate all the options.

Then with your object selected go to the *Properties Window > Object Tab > Duplication > Frames*

[image: Dupliframes]

Also see [Is there a way to convert a constraint to a keyframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-constraint-to-a-keyframe)

Comment: Thanks! How can I let all of those objects placed on the frames move around the circle like the first object did?

Comment: You could parent them again to the curve with thr *Follow Path* option, though you may have to deal manually with some sort of animation offset. Not sure.

Comment: Well, what a chore. However, I need that one-time, so it will work fine for now. Thanks!

Comment: See if this addon helps https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/ARewO I found it quite useful in a couple situations

Comment: Is there still no better way of doing this?