# How to show transforms of Child Of or Copy Transforms constraint

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, transforms, constraints

I am trying to find a way to make the transforms from a Child Of or Copy Transforms constraint visible.

Let's say the bone is in its default position and with the constraint activated changes to a position.
I need to keyframe any transforms out of the default position.

How could one accomplish this? Child Of and Copy Transforms constraints don't change the transforms.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it was an answer in this question: [Is there a way to convert a constraint to a keyframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-constraint-to-a-keyframe?rq=1)

You have to use Bake Action and then tick "Visual Keying" and probably also select the bone you want to bake the action for. This will make keyframes for any visual transforms.

Also in Pose Mode you can select bones and hit Ctrl+A and then use Apply Visual Transform.

I think you can insert keyframes for it with I -> Visual Transform too.