# is it possible to copy DEF bone animation to MCH?

Tags: rigging

hi I have a question about rigify rigsystem.

Is there a way to link DEF bones and MCH bones?
I guess until I copy the animation to MCH,I will not be able to use action from another armature rig...  (it just copy location of hips)

or maybe not from DEF, can be from ORG bones to MCH bones?

[image]

for additional explanation, It became like this because I tried to retarget animation from motion capture by using follow empty and target empty to constraint location and rotation to fk rig
 by following this tutorial > https://connect.unity.com/p/retargeting-animations-with-blender-2-80

[image]
and I baked and cleared constraints.
[image]
when I use the baked action to another rig, But it does not follow animation.
[image]

I guess I must be missing something.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if you use Pose->Animation->Bake Action with settings that i provide in this ansver -
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260999/62084

Comment: I will try the solution this weekend. I appriciate.