# What is the way to get location of the animated object

Tags: transforms, constraints, cache

I have an object animated using "Transform cache" constraint.
It is moving around the scene, but it's world location and rotation always stays the same.
I assume this happens due to some root empty inside it, that is not moving.
I am trying to get the exact world location of the animated object.
[image]
[image]
I tried to connect second object, and set "Copy location" "Copy rotation" constraints, it is following the first one, but location values are staying the same as well.
I tried to set cursor to the object - that way I can get location, but rotation is missing.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i got it.
Apply visual transform (select object Ctrl+A - Visual transform) for the second object, and then remove constraints.
Location and rotation transforms from the animation will apply to the second object.

Second answer in this question helped:
[Is there a way to convert a constraint to a keyframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-constraint-to-a-keyframe)